# AWS cloudfront - cache get request and forward request to server also

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am implementing a widget service which can be integrated in websites. For fast loading, I am using AWS Cloudfront.

One of the features of this widget is when users click on it, they get redirected to a specific url by our server and also that click is getting recorded in database right then.

Following below are the challenges, I'm stuck with -

1. How to cache a redirect with AWS. Cloudfront ? Ex - when user clicks on a widget, the request gets redirected to a url from CDN layer if, redirect-url exist in cdn cache.
2. How to forward that request to server in above scenario where redirect-url exist in CDN cache and is request gets fulfilled by CDN layer only. Objective is to record that click also.

Any help !!

Answer (score 1):

If the CDN is handling the request with a cached response, by design, your origin server should not need to know or do anything.

You could achieve this by your widget calling an AWS Lambda function that processes your redirect and then logs the request, possibly by making a call to your backend server.

Here is some more information on how to handle the redirect:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):

 # Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
 
 response = {
     'status': '302',
     'statusDescription': 'Found',
     'headers': {
         'location': [{
             'key': 'Location',
             'value': 'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html'
         }]
     }
 }
 
 return response
```